# How to include classpath resources in a Quarkus native image?

Tags: java, quarkus

It seems that by default the native image generated by Quarkus does not include any classpath resources corresponding to stuff from `src/main/resources/`.

From the [GraalVM docs](https://github.com/oracle/graal/blob/master/substratevm/RESOURCES.md), I sort of understand why this happens, but now I'm stuck. Is there a way to configure the `quarkus-maven-plugin` to include the resources in the native image?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

We have a layer to do that programmatically in extensions but, right now, we don't have any user facing API for applications.

So for the time being, you could use this option of the quarkus-maven-plugin:

```
 <quarkus.native.additional-build-args>-H:ResourceConfigurationFiles=resources-config.json</quarkus.native.additional-build-args>
```

Or you can also define it in your `application.properties`:

```
quarkus.native.additional-build-args =-H:ResourceConfigurationFiles=resources-config.json
```

Everything is documented here: https://quarkus.io/guides/writing-native-applications-tips .

Comment: Thanks, I've got it working now. I got confused by the single quotes from the GraalVM docs at first. So in the POM, you use `-H:IncludeResources=.*\.json`, but for a shell command, you would use `-H:IncludeResources='.*\.json'`

Comment: FYI, this way of adding build args does not work any more. Now it seems to be done via `mvn quarkus:native-image -Dquarkus.native.additional-build-args=-H:+PrintAnalysisCallTree`

Comment: What about using:
  `quarkus.native.resources.includes="resources/**"`
it does not seem to work