# How to access resources in a Quarkus native image?

Tags: docker, quarkus, graalvm, quarkus-native

I started playing with quarkus and graalvm. I added files (txt and jpg) to resources in the project (`src/main/resources/`). To be sure that I have access to this file in controller I display size of it:

```
URL url = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResource("/Resource2.txt");
File file = new File(url.toURI());
return "Hello My Friend! File size in bytes = " + file.length();
```

and when I run it with maven (`mvn quarkus:dev`) it works. Controller code is [here](https://github.com/sleski/hello-quarkus/blob/master/src/main/java/it/tostao/quickstart/GreetingResource.java).

Problem occurred when I created native Quarkus application and try to run inside docker.
To be sure that file is included in native image, I added a big jpg file (3.3MB), created `resources-config.json`:

```
{ "resources": 
 { "includes": [
        { "pattern": "IMG_3_3M\\.jpg$"},
        { "pattern": "Resources2\\.txt$"}
       ]
}}
```

and in `application.properties` added:
`quarkus.native.additional-build-args = -H:ResourceConfigurationFiles=resources-config.json`. The native runner size was increased from:

- `39M Mar 21 12:48 hello-quarkus-1.0-SNAPSHOT-runner`
- to: `44M Mar 21 12:19 hello-quarkus-1.0-SNAPSHOT-runner`

So I assume that jpg file was included, but still when run native application inside docker image, I got NPE:

```
 Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
  at it.tostao.quickstart.GreetingResource.hello(GreetingResource.java:24)
```

where line 24: is `url.toURI()`.

**Any idea how I can read resources in native image? Is something missing in the configuration?**

here is sample image to reproduce the problem, all commands needed to build and run native image you can find in [README.MD](https://github.com/sleski/hello-quarkus/blob/master/README.md):

https://github.com/sleski/hello-quarkus

So far I checked this urls and still was not able to find resources in native image:

• [How to include classpath resources in a Quarkus native image?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55300484/how-to-include-classpath-resources-in-a-quarkus-native-image)

• [How to read classpath resources in Quarkus native image?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55862872/how-to-read-classpath-resources-in-quarkus-native-image)

• https://quarkus.io/guides/writing-native-applications-tips

• [Read txt file from resources folder on maven Quarkus project From Docker Container](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60711034/read-txt-file-from-resources-folder-on-maven-quarkus-project-from-docker-contain)

Comment: Can you check if the url variable or the uri variable is null? If getResource() doesn't find it, it returns a null url. But doing new File(url.toUrl()) probably will never end up well in native image.

Comment: I checked, this returns null: `Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResource("/Resource2.txt");`
So looks like in Native image I am not able to find this resource, but why?
What should I use instead of `new File(url.toUrl())` in native image?

Comment: @GeoffreyDeSmet should I use something like this to find resources: https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus/blob/main/core/runtime/src/main/java/io/quarkus/runtime/ResourceHelper.java ?

Comment: Not sure - I haven't loaded image resources etc yet in quarkus native apps. But it must be possible. Double check if the file name matches case-sensitive (resource2.txt vs Resource2.txt). On windows, in an non-jarred classpath, case-sensitive would not break non-native, but would break native. If that's not it, and no one replies here, ask on Quarkus's zulip chat.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First fix json

```json
{
    "resources": [
      {
        "pattern": "Resource2.txt"
      }
    ]
}
```

or you can have *.txt as pattern. like in the [doc](https://quarkus.io/guides/writing-native-applications-tips#including-resources)

https://github.com/oracle/graal/blob/master/docs/reference-manual/native-image/Resources.md says use

```java
InputStream resource = ModuleLayer.boot().findModule(moduleName).getResourceAsStream(resourcePath);
```

when I tried I had issues. you can see the working code below for your project

```java
@Path("/hello")
public class GreetingResource {


    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
    public String hello() throws IOException {
        String moduleName = "java.base";
        String resourcePath = "/Resource2.txt";
        Module resource = ModuleLayer.boot().findModule(moduleName).get();
        InputStream ins = resource.getResourceAsStream(resourcePath);
        if (ins == null) {
            System.out.println("module came empty, now trying to load from GreetingResource");
            ins = GreetingResource.class.getResourceAsStream(resourcePath);
        }
        if (ins != null) {
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            for (int ch; (ch = ins.read()) != -1; ) {
                sb.append((char) ch);
            }
            return "Hello My Friend! File size in bytes = " + sb;
        }
        return "empty";
    }

}
```

`GreetingResource.class.getResourceAsStream(resourcePath);` is actually bringing the resource here. I think this feature may change in the future so I left ModuleLayer in the code too. I used graalvm 17-21.3.0

you can find the build log below

```
[INFO] [io.quarkus.deployment.pkg.steps.NativeImageBuildRunner] C:\Program Files\GraalVM\graalvm-ce-java17-21.3.0\bin\native-image.cmd -J-Dsun.nio.ch.maxUpdateArraySize=100 -J-Djava.util.logging.manager=org.jboss.logmanager.LogManager -J-Dvertx.logger-delegate-factory-class-name=io.quarkus.vertx.core.runtime.VertxLogDelegateFactory -J-Dvertx.disableDnsResolver=true -J-Dio.netty.leakDetection.level=DISABLED -J-Dio.netty.allocator.maxOrder=3 -J-Duser.language=en -J-Duser.country=GB -J-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -H:-ParseOnce -J--add-exports=java.security.jgss/sun.security.krb5=ALL-UNNAMED -J--add-opens=java.base/java.text=ALL-UNNAMED -H:ResourceConfigurationFiles=resources-config.json -H:+PrintAnalysisCallTree -H:Log=registerResource:verbose -H:InitialCollectionPolicy=com.oracle.svm.core.genscavenge.CollectionPolicy\$BySpaceAndTime -H:+JNI -H:+AllowFoldMethods -J-Djava.awt.headless=true -H:FallbackThreshold=0 -H:+ReportExceptionStackTraces -H:-AddAllCharsets -H:EnableURLProtocols=http -H:-UseServiceLoaderFeature -H:+StackTrace -J--add-exports=java.management/sun.management=ALL-UNNAMED hello-quarkus-1.0-SNAPSHOT-runner -jar hello-quarkus-1.0-SNAPSHOT-runner.jar
[hello-quarkus-1.0-SNAPSHOT-runner:20428]    classlist:   2,920.35 ms,  0.94 GB
[hello-quarkus-1.0-SNAPSHOT-runner:20428]        (cap):   1,493.84 ms,  0.94 GB
[hello-quarkus-1.0-SNAPSHOT-runner:20428]        setup:   2,871.07 ms,  0.94 GB
[Use -Dgraal.LogFile=<path> to redirect Graal log output to a file.]
[thread:1] scope: main
  [thread:1] scope: main.registerResource
  ResourcesFeature: registerResource: Resource2.txt
14:23:38,709 INFO  [org.jbo.threads] JBoss Threads version 3.4.2.Final
  [thread:1] scope: main.registerResource
  ResourcesFeature: registerResource: java/lang/uniName.dat
[hello-quarkus-1.0-SNAPSHOT-runner:20428]     (clinit):     475.20 ms,  5.14 GB
[hello-quarkus-1.0-SNAPSHOT-runner:20428]   (typeflow):   2,931.83 ms,  5.14 GB
[hello-quarkus-1.0-SNAPSHOT-runner:20428]    (objects):  24,294.27 ms,  5.14 GB
[hello-quarkus-1.0-SNAPSHOT-runner:20428]   (features):   2,979.07 ms,  5.14 GB
[hello-quarkus-1.0-SNAPSHOT-runner:20428]     analysis:  32,083.24 ms,  5.14 GB
# Printing call tree to: C:\Users\ozkan\tmp\hello-quarkus\target\hello-quarkus-1.0-SNAPSHOT-native-image-source-jar\reports\call_tree_hello-quarkus-1.0-SNAPSHOT-runner_20220324_142406.txt
# Printing list of used methods to: C:\Users\ozkan\tmp\hello-quarkus\target\hello-quarkus-1.0-SNAPSHOT-native-image-source-jar\reports\used_methods_hello-quarkus-1.0-SNAPSHOT-runner_20220324_142407.txt
# Printing list of used classes to: C:\Users\ozkan\tmp\hello-quarkus\target\hello-quarkus-1.0-SNAPSHOT-native-image-source-jar\reports\used_classes_hello-quarkus-1.0-SNAPSHOT-runner_20220324_142407.txt
# Printing list of used packages to: C:\Users\ozkan\tmp\hello-quarkus\target\hello-quarkus-1.0-SNAPSHOT-native-image-source-jar\reports\used_packages_hello-quarkus-1.0-SNAPSHOT-runner_20220324_142407.txt
# Printing call tree for vm entry point to: C:\Users\ozkan\tmp\hello-quarkus\target\hello-quarkus-1.0-SNAPSHOT-native-image-source-jar\reports\csv_call_tree_vm_hello-quarkus-1.0-SNAPSHOT-runner_20220324_142408.csv
# Printing call tree for methods to: C:\Users\ozkan\tmp\hello-quarkus\target\hello-quarkus-1.0-SNAPSHOT-native-image-source-jar\reports\csv_call_tree_methods_hello-quarkus-1.0-SNAPSHOT-runner_20220324_142408.csv
# Printing call tree for virtual methods to: C:\Users\ozkan\tmp\hello-quarkus\target\hello-quarkus-1.0-SNAPSHOT-native-image-source-jar\reports\csv_call_tree_virtual_methods_hello-quarkus-1.0-SNAPSHOT-runner_20220324_142408.csv
# Printing call tree for entry points to: C:\Users\ozkan\tmp\hello-quarkus\target\hello-quarkus-1.0-SNAPSHOT-native-image-source-jar\reports\csv_call_tree_entry_points_hello-quarkus-1.0-SNAPSHOT-runner_20220324_142408.csv
# Printing call tree for direct edges to: C:\Users\ozkan\tmp\hello-quarkus\target\hello-quarkus-1.0-SNAPSHOT-native-image-source-jar\reports\csv_call_tree_direct_edges_hello-quarkus-1.0-SNAPSHOT-runner_20220324_142408.csv
# Printing call tree for overriden by edges to: C:\Users\ozkan\tmp\hello-quarkus\target\hello-quarkus-1.0-SNAPSHOT-native-image-source-jar\reports\csv_call_tree_override_by_edges_hello-quarkus-1.0-SNAPSHOT-runner_20220324_142408.csv
# Printing call tree for virtual edges to: C:\Users\ozkan\tmp\hello-quarkus\target\hello-quarkus-1.0-SNAPSHOT-native-image-source-jar\reports\csv_call_tree_virtual_edges_hello-quarkus-1.0-SNAPSHOT-runner_20220324_142408.csv
[hello-quarkus-1.0-SNAPSHOT-runner:20428]     universe:   1,547.28 ms,  5.14 GB
[hello-quarkus-1.0-SNAPSHOT-runner:20428]      (parse):   4,919.32 ms,  4.87 GB
[hello-quarkus-1.0-SNAPSHOT-runner:20428]     (inline):   7,013.78 ms,  5.83 GB
[hello-quarkus-1.0-SNAPSHOT-runner:20428]    (compile):  27,387.04 ms,  5.56 GB
[hello-quarkus-1.0-SNAPSHOT-runner:20428]      compile:  41,595.59 ms,  5.56 GB
[hello-quarkus-1.0-SNAPSHOT-runner:20428]        image:   2,515.22 ms,  5.56 GB
[hello-quarkus-1.0-SNAPSHOT-runner:20428]        write:     858.79 ms,  5.56 GB
[hello-quarkus-1.0-SNAPSHOT-runner:20428]      [total]:  90,068.97 ms,  5.56 GB
# Printing build artifacts to: C:\Users\ozkan\tmp\hello-quarkus\target\hello-quarkus-1.0-SNAPSHOT-native-image-source-jar\hello-quarkus-1.0-SNAPSHOT-runner.build_artifacts.txt
[INFO] [io.quarkus.deployment.QuarkusAugmentor] Quarkus augmentation completed in 94323ms
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  01:37 min
[INFO] Finished at: 2022-03-24T14:24:56Z
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: well this worked for me I was using micronaut framework for building a native image using graal-vm 17

Answer (score 0):

This is how I solved the problem - example with changes are in this branch: https://github.com/sleski/hello-quarkus/tree/solution_for_native

Explanations:

Image is in: `src/main/resources/images` and name is:`IMG_3_3M.jpg`.
In `application.properties` I added `images.location` variable:

```
images.location=src/main/resources/images/
%prod.images.location=/work/images/
```

and in the java controller I added:

```
@ConfigProperty(name = "images.location")
String imageLocation;
```

in `docker.native` added: `COPY target/classes/images/*.jpg /work/images/`

When I start application with `querkus:dev` it is getting image from `src/main/resources/images` and when I run narive image: `/work/images`.

In both cases work: `File size is = 3412177`.